# Java SAX parsing of an XML String

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing, saxparser

I have a situation, where I get a string representation of an XML and I would like to parse it using SAX parser.

I know there is a way to use document builder in order to get a DOM document and parse it using DOM parser, but I would like to parse it using SAX.

I don't want to save it to a file and read it using the SAX parser, unless this is the only option.

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  `SAXParser.parse(InputSource is, DefaultHandler dh)` where

```
 InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(str));
```

Comment: how would a method that gets the string as an argument look like? what will parse return? can you please edit and write it as a method?

Comment: something like: `public static Document loadXML(String xml) throws Exception
{
   DocumentBuilderFactory fctr = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder bldr = fctr.newDocumentBuilder();
   InputSource insrc = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
   return bldr.parse(insrc);
}`

Comment: sorry but it didn't help.. I'm new to this so any chance you can elaborate?

Comment: SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser().parse(inputSource, defaultHandler); the processing of events happens in DefaultHandler, you need to write it yourself